# Carriage Returns in Markdown Section of IPython Notebook

Tags: ipython, markdown

Is there a way to execute carriage returns in a markdown section of an IPython notebook so that when executed the text remains on separate lines (as displayed when typing), rather than combining all text into a single block of text?

Below is my input (and how it displays while typing), followed by the resulting output when the markdown section is executed.

Input:

```
XXXX [carriage return]
YYYY [carriage return]
ZZZZ [carriage return]
```

Output:

```
XXXX YYYY ZZZZ
```

I am able to create paragraphs by typing text, [carriage return], [space], text, [carriage return] (see below), but I am unable to display consecutive individual lines of text without some placeholder on the line between each line of text.

Input:

```
Paragraph 1 [carriage return] [space]

Paragraph 2 [carriage return] [space]

Paragraph 3
```

Output:

```
Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2

Paragraph 3
```

Am I missing something easy?

Answer (score 34):

As per [the Markdown specification](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p),  `<br>` tags can be inserted by ending a line with two or more spaces:

> ### Paragraphs and line breaks
>
> A paragraph is simply one or more consecutive lines of text, separated by one or more blank lines. (A blank line is any line that looks like a blank line — a line containing nothing but spaces or tabs is considered blank.) Normal paragraphs should not be indented with spaces or tabs.
>
> The implication of the "one or more consecutive lines of text" rule is that Markdown supports "hard-wrapped" text paragraphs. This differs significantly from most other text-to-HTML formatters (including Movable Type's "Convert Line Breaks" option) which translate every line break character in a paragraph into a `<br />` tag.
>
> When you do want to insert a `<br />` break tag using Markdown, you end a line with two or more spaces, then type return.
>
> Yes, this takes a tad more effort to create a `<br />`, but a simplistic "every line break is a `<br />`" rule wouldn't work for Markdown. Markdown's email-style blockquoting and multi-paragraph list items work best — and look better — when you format them with hard breaks.

So something like

```
XXXX␣␣
YYYY␣␣
ZZZZ
```

(using `␣` to represent spaces) should work.

Comment: Thanks! This really works. But it's quite a bad solution technically (trailing whitespace!). Many people configure their editors to clean trailing whitespace. Why not "two spaces in the following line"? (not asking you, just the MD guys)

Comment: Using the second approach with the double spaces will also avoid rendering problems with `<br />` when the notebook is exported in PDF, using LaTeX. In other words, `<br />` won't print a new line in the PDF.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply put 2 spaces after `xxxx [2 spaces + enter], yyyy [2 spaces + enter] and zzzz [2 spaces + enter]`.