# Include carriage return correctly in iPython notebooks when writing using json.dump

Tags: python, json, markdown, jupyter-notebook, carriage-return

I'm trying to generate iPython notebooks as json files with Python.  I'm not sure how to write carriage returns to file in cells that I've specified as `cell_type` markdown.  I've tried double spaces, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188124/carriage-returns-in-markdown-section-of-ipython-notebook), and I can get the markdown to make a new line by specifying `<br />` but if I include a header specification to the markdown it treats the whole input as a header.

For instance:

```
import json

# Single markdown cell as a dictionary
cell = {
  "cell_type" : "markdown",
  "metadata" : {'collapsed': False, 'name': 'test'},
  "source" : ["## Header line",
    "<br />", 
    "Second line, not a header...hopefully"],
}

# Create ipython notebook dictionary
nbdict = { 'metadata': {}, \
    'nbformat': 4,
    'nbformat_minor': 0,
    'cells': [cell]
    }

with open('test.ipynb', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(nbdict, outfile)
```

Then if I open this with `ipython notebook test.ipynb` I have the following output:

**Header line Second line, not a header...hopefully**

But it's all in bold type, so the whole input is being treated as a one line header.

How do I specify carriage returns properly, so that headers are honoured for just a single line, when I'm creating these notebooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown uses *newlines* to separate lines, not HTML `<br/>` tags. Include newlines in your source lines; use double newlines to separate paragraph elements (including headers):

```
cell = {
    "cell_type": "markdown",
    "metadata": {'collapsed': False, 'name': 'test'},
    "source": [
        "## Header line\n\n",
        "Second line, not a header...hopefully"
    ],
}
```